# Reload Apache from Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, reload

I have an application which allows users to add there own domains and forward them to particular CNAME so that it works with our application.

For my part, I just need to add a ServerAlias for the domain in my vhost file and reload the apache.

I understand that rails app won't have necessary privileges to reload apache.

So, what is the best and secure way to accomplish  this -- the reload stuff?

Thanks,
Imran

Comment: You may be better off using mod_rewrite for something like that.  Then you wouldn't need consistent restarts, which are bad.

Comment: I understand, but mod_rewrite is not the option here -- at least to the extent I can think of.

This is reload not restart, and it won't be that consistent. May be a few times in whole month. But they need to be real time as a new domain gets added.

Can I add the www-data to sudoers to execute a particular command only or run a certain bash script -- of course this would be apache reload script.

Comment: How about creating a daemon to look for any changes in sites-enabled/available folder, and trigger apache reload as any file gets changed. If this is a feasible option, could anyone please get me going through the daemon thing -- step by step, as I never worked with this before? :)

Comment: Here's an example of a ruby script that monitors file system events: http://paulhorman.com/filesystemwatcher/  
And here's a gem for turning a script into a daemon: http://daemons.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should catch *.your.domain and then do a domain detection (including 404 if the domain is invalid) in your Rails application.